# How to bring LSOA data up to MSOA level London using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, regression, aggregation

I need to preform regression analysis but my issue is that I have data at 2 different Output areas, MSOA and LSOA. My question is, how to I bring my LSOA data up to MSOA level?

Comment: For starters, it's a good idea to spell out acronyms that might not be as well known in other parts of the world. It didn't take me long to find out you meant lower and middle layer super output areas from the Office of National Statistics, but I did have to look. Next, what format is your data in, raster or vector? That will significantly impact answers. The operation you want to perform is called aggregation (or possibly resampling if raster). Do a collection of LSOAs coincide with a single MSOA, or can an LSOA be split between two or more MSOAs? That will also affect complexity of solution.

Comment: Hi Chris apologies for the use of acronyms. I'm new to gis exchange but understand now how stupid it was to use them. Thanks for your response. The data I have is in excel format so vector. A middle level output area contains multiple lower super output polygons. The fit within a middle layer output area. I will look into aggregating the data now. Thanks again James

Comment: Excel isn't vector, it's tabular. Do you have shapefiles or some other vector format that actually has the outlines of each LSOA/MSOA? If not you'll need to locate some, and if so the first step will be to join the Excel files (or possibly convert them to csv or geodatabase tables) to your shapes. At that point there's a couple more steps to get them combined, unless your LSOA data already has an attribute that indicates which MSOA it belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to get a shapefile with the boundaries that need (in this case the MSOA) and then use a spatial join by going to Vector > Data Management > Join be location in QGIS. In Arcgis you can just right click a layer and go to Join...

Actually I find it weird that you have MSOA only level data as usually they are LSOA or borough level. The LSOA you have is probably available at MSOA but with the join described above it's really easy to get it.